# total view debugger - debugging a process thats forked from a startup process at launch

Tags: debugging, totalview

I have application that has two executables. One that we launch and it forks n instances of the other.

Now I have to debug the second tsk file at launch. I can do it later using the attach to process option. But during launch, there seems to be some memory stuff that I need to debug.

Is there a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you link your program with the dbfork library, totalview should automatically attach to the forked process.

See “Linking with the dbfork Library” contained in the “Compilers and Platforms” Chapter of the TotalView Reference Guide.